# PDF Reader for Linux with Themes

Tags: linux, pdf

Are there any pdf readers for Linux that support colors out of the box ? I need a PDF reader which can switch themes like VIM's :colorscheme functionality .  Adobes Pdf Reader has Color option in Accessibility Screen , but you can have only just 1 color selected . I need to toggle depending on the lighting and what suits my eyes . Android has Moon Reader whose Themes are really good . Does Linux have anything that you can recommend ?

PS : I would think this is relevant to a Linux User who needs to read PDF's more than any specific product . We do have a plethora of reader in Android that has lots of viewing themes but I see none in Linux and I think its actually a necessity much like having Desktop Themes .

Comment: Zathura looks good it has a ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc where you can set a lot of things like for example https://bitbucket.org/runiq/dotfiles/src/d9726779d454/files/config/zathura/zathurarc

Comment: Looks great! Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I use `qpdf`. It allows the user to set background (page) color. While it isn't toggling, you can easily change the appearance of pages.

[image: qpdf settings]

Comment: Interesting but how do I change the font color , Background Color and Paper Color are for the Paper and the BG not the font - Any idea ?

Comment: Hi, did you also try the "Invert colors" option?

Comment: Since its off-topic question I am adding a comment about Zathura . It looks good and  has a ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc where you can set a lot of things like for example https://bitbucket.org/runiq/dotfiles/src/d9726779d454/files/config/zathura/zathurarc and it is vim like !